# Qt and grouping by rectangle with qt designer

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, qt4, qt-designer

Suppose i have a `QFrame`, I have 3 categories `widgets` in my `Frame`, Such as :`CheckBoxes` , `Buttons` and `texts`.

**My questions** is , How put every category in a rectangle ? (i didn't found in `qt-designer`)

Comment: What about putting each category into a separate widget?

Comment: not separate widget, but only in rectangle.

Comment: Well I don't know about that, why is it a problem for you tu add the widgets into your window instead of all the items separately? My app using white widgets grouping other elements https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108649284/screen.png

Comment: Composite widgets in docs http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#composite-widgets

Comment: or you can use `QFrame` instead of plain `QWidget`, should be simpler to style the border (frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt-Designer you can simply put `QGroupBox` widgets in your `QFrame` widget (in your case 3 `QGroupBox`), and then arrange all your widgets (CheckBoxes , Buttons and texts) in that 3 `QGroupBox` widgets. `QGroupBox` is rectangle and you can set name (title) of group box also in Qt-Designer if you need it. I am using PyQt 4.7.